# mongoid, query with element in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have structure class like this:

```
#<Transaction _id: 54d46d6a6e6f626fbcc70000,  _keywords: ["1", "test1", "test2", "abc1", "projectmongo", "last2", "taka"]>
```

array keyword map with: [field1, field2,...]
So I want to query to get all transaction have field1 == "1"
Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean fetching all `Transaction` records, where only first element in `_keywords` array == "1"?

Comment: fetching All, and merge with other filters. Like it: Transaction.where(:company=> params[:company]).where(:_keywords.0 => "1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). Don't expect there to be a "rails like" SQL ORM mapping equivalent when using functionality like arrays which are generally not supported for those storage engines:

```
Class.collection.find({ "_keywords.0" => "1" })
```

So the Moped syntax here is more raw to the MongoDB functionality.

That basically says "look at the first array element to see if it matches the value I ask for".

Comment: I use "where" to query. Beacause it have many ohter filters. Can you write it in rails mongoid syntax, please ?

Comment: @Peter_175 The very point I made is that there "is no Rails Syntax" for this because there is nothing that correlates to SQL Datastores in what you are asking. It works. If you expect it to work across different storage engines then you have a how different problem to solve.

Comment: Yep. So I must convert "where" syntax to collection.find. Thanks @Neil :)